# numerical analysis problem using Octave(Matlab)

Tags: floating-point, octave, ieee-754

[image]

[image]

[image]

⁞

[image]

These are the numbers expressed in terms of IEEE-64 by using floating point representation. I want to write a code using Octave to express all the above numbers by using while-loop. So, I tried like this.

```
x=2^(1023);
t=1;
r=2^(t)-1;
k=1+r*(2^(-52));
while x < 2^(1024)
  t=t+1;
  r=r;
  k=k;
  x=x*k;
  xmax=x
  fprintf('x=x*(%4d)=%20.19e \n',k,xmax)
  %pause  
endwhile
```

But this code never stops.. how can I solve this problem..?

Comment: How do you know the code never stops? In IEEE-754 binary64, there are 2^52 numbers with exponent 1023. If your computer iterates through a trillion (about 2^40) a second, it would take about 2^52/2^40 = 2^12 = 4096 seconds, which is over an hour. If your computer does not do that many per second, it will make hours, possibly many hours for it to finish. Did you wait long enough?

Comment: In any case, you do not want to iterate by multiplying `x`. Set `E` to 2^(1023−52), as the exponent portion of the floating-point representation. Then iterate `f` from 2^52 to 2^53 by 1, as a simple arithmetic progression, no multiplication. In each iteration, the floating-point number is f•E. This will generate all IEEE-754 binary64 numbers with exponent 1023. It will still take a long time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, I didn’t wait so long enough, but I found that the values ‘k’ are same in each outputs. Thus, the codes produce same ‘xmax’ values over and over again. I felt it is wrong to wait that too long.

Comment: `k` is the same in each iteration because you never change it; the only assignment to `k` in the loop is `k=k`.

Comment: Hmm... could you please fix some codes there?

Comment: I do not use Octave. Iterate through all values by iterating `f` from 2^52 to 2^53 and printing `f` times 2^(1023−52).

Comment: When I converted the code, as best I understand it, to C and ran it, the values printed for `xmax` were changing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I will try it... thanks!

Comment: Also, on my system, about five years old now, running the program using C with a `printf` statement similar to the `fprintf` shown in the question printed about a billion times in 186 seconds, so 2^52 times would take 2^52/1e9•186 seconds, which is over 26 years. And that is with output directed to `/dev/null`, which discards it. Outputting to a terminal window or file would take longer.